# Why $\{A_n \quad a.a.\}:=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k$ is not defined as $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k$?

Tags: probability

Given a probability tripple $(\Omega, F, P)$ and infinite many events $A_1, A_2, \dots, \in F$, a new event "almost always" in $F$ is normally defined as:

$$\{A_n \quad a.a.\}:=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k$$

I'm wondering, why it is not defined as 
$$\{A_n \quad a.a.\}:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k$$
? The two definitions look equivalent to me and the latter is easier to understand.

Comment: How do you define the limit of a sequence of sets? Wouldn't that amount to the same definition as the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first definition is easiest to understand in my opinion. It describes all those sets for which only finitely many $A_n$ are not in $F$.

> Regarding your suggestion the [set-theoretic
>   limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_limit) is defined
>   as follows. Let the *limit infinum* and *limit supremum* be defined as
>   \begin{equation*} \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n = \bigcup_{n \geq
>  1} \bigcap_{j \geq n} A_j \qquad \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n =
> \bigcap_{n \geq 1} \bigcup_{j \geq n} A_j. \end{equation*} If the two
>   coincide the set theoretic limit exists and is equal to the resulting
>   set.

You can see that the first definition for "almost always in $F$" is equal to $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n$. As pointed out in the comments $B_n = \bigcap_{j \geq n} A_j$ is an increasing sequence and thus $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} B_n = \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}B_n = \bigcup_{n \geq
 1} \bigcap_{j \geq n} B_j = \bigcup_{n \geq
 1} B_n = \bigcup_{n \geq
 1} \bigcap_{j \geq n} A_j= \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n.$$

Comment: OP meant the limit of $B_n=\cap_{k=n}^\infty A_k$, not of $A_n$ itself. If the sequence of sets is monotone increasing (with respect to inclusion) then the limit exists and it just equals to the union of the sets.

Comment: Of course you're right, my mistake. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent indeed. But why do you think your definition is easier to understand? The first definition makes perfect sense: there exists some $n$ such that all the events $A_k$ starting from $n$ are happening. It is clear that it means that all but finitely many number of the events are happening. On the other hand the definition with limits is not very intuitive.